# Setting SOAP fault in Mule

Tags: exception, soap, mule

Currently this is how I'm catching exception and setting the payload

```
<catch-exception-strategy name="Catch_Exception_Strategy">
   <logger message="#[exception.summaryMessage]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
   <set-payload value="Error in service operation" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

But, CXF SOAP component sets the payload of real response object. While I want to send an error object in a SOAP Fault instead. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

### Update

Default exception strategy sends SOAP Fault with error message. Initially my purpose was to just add the logger and let the default error message go in the SOAP Fault. I added Catch exception strategy but later found out it does not send SOAP fault. Instead then I used Rollback strategy that send SOAP fault. However, there was not much benefit of logging exception inside strategy block using Mule Logger as it is already logged by Mule.

Now, I realize the advantage of using cxf:outFaultInterceptor. You can not only add custom elements to SOAP Fault but you can also segregate custom logs in separate log file. Thanks Anirban for providing sample interceptor class.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it..
One of the way is using a expression component in Catch block like the following :-

```
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
  <set-variable variableName="id" value="Invalid Request !!!" doc:name="Variable"/>
  <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload=&quot;&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'&gt;\n  
   &lt;soap:Body&gt;\n      &lt;soap:Fault&gt;\n      &lt;faultcode&gt;INVALID_REQUEST&lt;/faultcode&gt;\n      &lt;faultstring&gt;Invalid Request&lt;/faultstring&gt;\n      &lt;detail&gt;\n      &lt;ns4:Fault xmlns='http://services.test.com/schema/report/SendReport' xmlns:ns4='http://services.test.com/schema/common/Fault'&gt;\n      &lt;ns4:errCode&gt;-2&lt;/ns4:errCode&gt;\n      &lt;ns4:errorDesc&gt;System Fault&lt;/ns4:errorDesc&gt;\n      &lt;ns4:stackTrace&gt;Invalid Request.Please  ensure that you use the correct request header as per the schema&lt;/ns4:stackTrace&gt;\n      &lt;/ns4:Fault&gt;\n      &lt;/detail&gt;\n      &lt;/soap:Fault&gt;\n     &lt;/soap:Body&gt;\n    &lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;&quot;]" doc:name="Expression_Custom_Fault_Response"/>
  </catch-exception-strategy>
```

Other way is to use Custom Java class in CXF fault interceptor :-

```
<cxf:jaxws-service service="MainData" serviceClass="Your Service class"  doc:name="SOAPWithHeader" >
<cxf:outFaultInterceptors>  
<spring:bean id="outfault" class="Your custom fault interceptor Java Class"/>
</cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:jaxws-service>
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Customise the fault interceptor class :-

```
public class CustomSoapFault extends AbstractSoapInterceptor
 {
            private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CustomSoapFaultOutInterceptor.class);

        public CustomSoapFault() 
             {
                super(Phase.MARSHAL);
                getAfter().add(Soap11FaultOutInterceptor.class.getName());
             }
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault
             {
                Fault fault = (Fault) message.getContent(Exception.class);
                logger.error(fault.getMessage(), fault);
            //custom message in response
     Element detail = fault.getOrCreateDetail();
                Element errorDetail = detail.getOwnerDocument().createElement("error-reply");
                Element error = errorDetail.getOwnerDocument().createElement("error");
                Element extRefNumber = errorDetail.getOwnerDocument().createElement("ExternalReferenceNumber");
                Element partnerId = errorDetail.getOwnerDocument().createElement("PartnerID");

                partnerId.setTextContent("123");
                extRefNumber.setTextContent("321");
                error.setTextContent("Contact the administrator");

                errorDetail.appendChild(error);
                errorDetail.appendChild(extRefNumber);
                errorDetail.appendChild(partnerId);
                detail.appendChild(errorDetail);
              }

  }
```

//Provide the class in CXF interceptor

```
<cxf:jaxws-service>
   <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
      <spring:bean class="com.mypackage.mule.interceptor.CustomSoapFault"/>
   </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:jaxws-service>
```

Comment: None of the above will work with CXF SOAP component. Any other way?

Comment: These are the most common ways that works with CXF Soap webservice .. If you are facing issue or unable to configure .. update your question with the approach you tried .. by that way it will be easy to detect the issue you are facing ...

Comment: First option is same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383639/how-to-throw-soap-fault-manually-in-mule which is applicable in cxf proxy service but not in jax-ws case

Comment: In second option, what object will I return from custom java class? I think I need to add custom message type for fault in WSDL and return it from java class...

Comment: The first option is a way to display customized response in case of an exception .. you can use it even in jax-ws service .... It will execute and display in the case of exception ... The second option allows you to control more on fault .. you can customise your message as per exception with second option .. you can have different messages as per different exception type

Comment: Catch strategy does not through soap fault. If you simply set the payload using an expression, it will marshal response object using that payload instead of throwing soap fault

Comment: Yes for handling marshaling issue in SOAP you need to go for option2 using CXF fault interceptor

Comment: See the example of interceptor class :- https://gist.github.com/ricston-git/3864598 ... you can modify the class according to your requerment and use it into <cxf:outFaultInterceptors> <spring:bean id="outfault" class="Your custom fault interceptor Java Class"/> </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>

Comment: Thanks, I have changed to Rollback strategy with a logger

Comment: Pls check my updated answer .. why don't you try this

Comment: You can provide customise details and can handle SOAP fault very easily