# Apache CXF (Mule) Invalid QName in mapping: SOAP-ENV:Client

Tags: soap, cxf, mule

I'm using Apache CXF 2.5.9 within Mule ESB 3.5.0 CE for a Web Service client. If the soap message validation fails on server I get a soap fault (naturally) that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
   <faultstring>https://10.1.104.105:8444/DohvatiIzOIBaF2FAServiceTest: cvc-simple-type 1: element {http://www.apis-it.hr/fin/2008/elements/DohvatIzOIBa}OIB value '716500116650' is not a valid instance of type {http://www.apis-it.hr/fin/2008/types/f63}String11BrojType</faultstring>
   <faultactor>OIB CIS pristupni čvor</faultactor>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

..but when client side tries to unmarshall the fault I get this exception:

```
2014-12-13 13:52:34,199 [WARN] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://www.apis-it.hr/fin/2010/services/DohvatiIzOIBaF2FAService}DohvatiIzOIBaF2ServicePortTypeService#{http://www.apis-it.hr/fin/2010/services/DohvatiIzOIBaF2FAService}DohvatiFOPoOIBu has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid QName in mapping: SOAP-ENV:Client
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readQName(StaxUtils.java:1399)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:801)
```

I want the CXF client to unmarshall the soap fault to exception. How to get around this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try making SOAP-ENV:Client something like this 12345, making the fault code a number solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mule won't catch the exception itself.
You should probably use a [cxf fault interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959634/setting-soap-fault-in-mule). From there you can compose the message you are expecting.

Comment: Victor, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't help me. First I need to get arount the "Invalid QName in mapping" exception in order to handle the soap fault. But shouldn't the CXF client component convert the incoming soap fault into an exception and throw it?

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you could use the CXF [transform feature](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html#TransformationFeature-Replacingtextcontent)

You need:
`<entry key="faultcode" value="faultcode=soapenv:Client"/>`

This will map the original invalid fault from the server into the following valid fault so that it can be accepted by the cxf client

```
<soapenv:Fault>
 <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
 <faultstring>An error occurred</faultstring>
</soapenv:Fault>
```